# ADFS 2.0 SSO specific application link

Tags: javascript, single-sign-on, adfs

Did some searching on both Google and Stackoverflow and unable to find an answer on this.

I have an ADFS portal where I can select about 5 different services.

I'm trying to figure out how I can capture a link to go to a specific service in that list, instead of providing the dropdown list as a whole.

The idea is that I'll host the link on our intranet with some other tools.

Ideally users would be able to just hit this link and be dropped into the service.

When I look at the view source of the portal with the dropdown, its all javascript and done by using variables.

Does anyone know how to capture or create a link to a specific application instead of using the portal?

Hope that makes sense.

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

That should be possible, the WS-Federation supports the selection of the home realm by using the `whr` parameter.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2424.windows-identity-foundation-wif-how-to-utilize-the-ws-federation-whr-parameter-to-bypass-home-realm-discovery-hrd.aspx